# DNS lookup for RDS times out

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance `my_instance` and a lambda. Both sit on the same VPC.

The RDS has a SC `my-security-group-rds` and lambda another security group `my-security-group-lambda`.

`my-security-group-lambda` has outbound rule without constraints. All protocols with IP 0.0.0.0/0.

`my-security-group-rds` has an inbound rule that allows any access from `my-security-group-lambda`.

Inside the lambda I want to perform DNS resolution of the hostname:

```
def dns_lookup(domainname,record_type,*dnsserver):
    """
    Get dns lookup results
    :param domain:
    :return: list of dns lookup results
    """
    try:
        lookup_result_list = []
        myResolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
        if not dnsserver:
            lookupAnswer = myResolver.query(domainname, record_type)
        else:
            myResolver.nameservers = dnsserver[0]
            lookupAnswer = myResolver.query(domainname,record_type)
        for answer in lookupAnswer:
            lookup_result_list.append(str(answer))
        return lookup_result_list
    except Exception as err:
        logger.exception("Not able to lookup DNS:{}".format(err))
        raise
```

I first perform the dns_lookup on the rds regional server, which works out nicely.

```
listOfAuthoritiveNames = dns_lookup("eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com", "NS")
```

Then I try to perform dns lookup on my instance:

```
dns_lookup("my-database.dfafda.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com", "A", listOfAuthoritiveNames)
```

This gives a timeout. If I use a wrong hostname for the database it says that there is no record, so it would seem that it has access to the nameservers.

Any idea what might be missing?

Comment: Lambda doesn't have internet access by default. If for this activity your lambda needs internet, you have to give access to it.

Comment: When you say "my-security-group-rds has an inbound rule that allows any access from my-security-group-lambda" what port did you assign on the inbound rule?

Comment: @AllanChua all traffic on all ports

Comment: @Riz not sure. DNS lookup is working for certain because if the address is wrong the result is no record

Comment: Is your lambda connected to VPC? Also is your DB `publicly accessible`?

Comment: DB is not publicly accessible. Both lambda and db belong to the vpc

Answer (score 0):

Hi for what I'm seeing you are missing the role for the lambda. Follow this steps:

- Open the Roles page of the IAM console and choose Create role.
- For the **Trusted entity type**, choose AWS Service, and for the Use case, choose Lambda.
- Choose Next.
- Add the IAM managed policies by doing the following:
- Using the policy search box, search for `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`.
- In the results list, select the check box next to the role, then choose **Clear filters**.
- Using the policy search box, search for additional role permission `AWSLambda...ExecutionRole`.
  In the results list, select the check box next to the role, then choose Next.
- For the Role name, enter `lambda-vpcname-role`, then choose Create role.

Using AWS CLI : pass your lambda role and sg lambda.

```
aws lambda create-function --function-name LambdaFunctionWithRDS --runtime python3.9 \
--zip-file fileb://lambda_function.zip --handler lambda_function.lambda_handler \
--role arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/lambda-vpc-sqs-role \
--vpc-config SubnetIds=subnet-1234567890abcdef0,subnet-abcdef01234567890,\
subnet-021345abcdef6789,subnet-1234abcdef567890,SecurityGroupIds=sg-1234567890abcdef0
```

Hope this helps

Reference:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html#w122aac77d191c13c27